# Installing Windows 10 from an ISO Image on my new 15 inch MacBook Pro 2016 with Touch bar

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, startup

Recently I've bought a new **15-inch MacBook Pro 2016 with Touch bar** and I tried to install **windows 10** using an ISO image and bootcamp. Everything was going well until I got the following error in my laptop's boot area within the Windows 10 installation environment:

[image: The Error]

**Windows cannot locate the disk and partition specified in the unattend answer file's `<ImageInstall>` setting.**

I know that Editing the XML file for the answer system can solve the problem, but how? As you know in this version of MacBook Pro no USB stick is used to install Windows and I cannot find where macOS stores the files created by bootcamp for installing windows.

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: How did you create the installation ISO?  The error you are getting is from an ISO created for volume deployment.

Comment: I downloaded the ISO separately and using this ISO, I've installed windows 10 several time on my other mac. And I tried Bootcamp to use this ISO for installation.

Comment: 1) What's the difference between this Mac and the other Mac and 2) did you download all of the bootcamp drivers?

Comment: @Allan In this version of Mac Bootcamp only asks for the ISO image, after you refer to the image it asks you to choose the size of the bootcamp partition then it starts downloading windows support software and making the iso ready for installation. Then it automatically reboots the laptop and guides you to windows 10 installation environment. All said means that it doesn't use a USB drive to burn the ISO to it and it does it using the internal hard. on other versions the ISO was burned to a USB drive and the windows was installed using that USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do such sophisticated thing. All you need to do is:

After making a second partition for windows:

1. Provide an external super drive and insert the DVD of windows 10 inside it.
2. You will find out that your trackpad and keyboard are not functioning in the following steps of windows 10 installation.
3. Therefore you should use a mouse (I prefer wired mouse) and an external keyboard.
4. Finally when the installation finished, ***download bootcamp* separately from apple and install it then you'll see that all of the features of you MacBook Pro are greatly working such as trackpad, keyboard, bluetooth, graphic and etc.**

Answer (score 0):

If the ISO file you’re trying to install is on an external drive, moving it to built in memory and retrying might help. Because it seems Windows do not have permissions to access external drives and hence can’t proceed with the ISO at that stage.